# Should I buffer both ends when `io::copy`ing from stdin to TcpStream and vice-versa?

Tags: tcp, io, rust, buffer

I [read](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/io/index.html#bufreader-and-bufwriter) that it is good practice to wrap io readers and writers with `BufRead` and `BufWrite` so as not to rely on too many system calls. I also understand that this is about *performance*.

I need to read data from [`io::stdin`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/io/fn.stdin.html) and to directly write it into a [`TcpStream`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.TcpStream.html). Similarly, I also need to read data from [`TcpStream`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.TcpStream.html) and directly write it to [`io::stdout`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/io/fn.stdout.html). By "directly", I mean that I need not have all this data written into memory meanwhile.

I think that [`io::copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/io/fn.copy.html) is the function I need to connect readers to writers this way.

However, I wonder whether it is good practise to [`buffer`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/io/index.html#bufreader-and-bufwriter) both ends of the streams plugged into [`io::copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/io/fn.copy.html):

- It feels good because it will limitate the number of system calls needed to transfer all data, is this correct?
- It feels bad because more data copies are needed to perform the transfer, *i.e.* `stdin -> BufReader -> BufWrite -> TcpStream` instead of `stdin -> TcpStream`, and the other way round `TcpStream -> BufRead -> BufWrite -> stdout` instead of `TcpStream -> stdout`, is this correct as well?

What's the tradeoff in play here? Should I buffer either end of the streams joined by [`io::copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/io/fn.copy.html) or not?
How does it depend on the amount of data, on the network or on the system?

Comment: Did you look at the code of `copy`?

Comment: @Stargateur I did not. Are you suggesting that `io::copy` could be already implemented with one intermediate buffer? :)

Comment: Well, it seems that [it is](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/src/std/io/util.rs.html#43-69), which makes it useless to buffer either end :)

Comment: Well, yes, copy could be implemented using OS directly, but this is not possible for various and complex reason, so when you want copy something on something else you always need to copy it at least one time in the user space, so copy is forced to use a buffer anyway. copy exist specifically for your use case. But don't worry it's perfectly normal and fast.

Comment: @Stargateur Crystal clear, thanks! Don't hesitate to post this as an answer :)